# Kashrut - Why is Halal label on Kosher meat?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I have noticed that Of Tov has Halal listed on their meat products. How is this halakhically possible? The Quran teaches that Kosher meat is not permissible for Muslims only grain is permissible. How are certain kosher companies allowing Halal to be placed on their product?

I usually buy Of Tov but in this regards I no longer would want to purchase their product simply because Halal is not Kosher and Kosher is not Halal.

Comment: I don't quite understand why there is a problem with a product having multiple symbols? If there is a kosher symbol, it's kosher! How does Halal negate that fact?

Comment: Yossi, we don't know anything about Halal laws. This is a site about Judaism. Don't trust us.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is purely anecdotal, but...

I have had several Muslim colleagues in the past.  They often buy Kosher meat as they acknowledged that Islamic meat laws were less strict than Kosher meat laws, and therefore any Kosher meat was automatically Halal as well.  Compounding this was that (at the time) there were no national laws governing Halal, so anyone could say that meat was Halal with no "proof" or recognizable Halal "hechsher".  Some of these people told me (and I personally witnessed) them buying Kosher meat because it had reliable, legal "supervision".

Comment: A superset, I assume?

Comment: @msh210 The Islamic meat laws are a subset of Kosher meat laws. Therefore Halal meat is a superset of kosher meat.

Comment: I have changed the wording to clarify the answer

Comment: Not in all cases: for example food cooked or preserved in alcohol would not be Halal

Answer (score 2):

[Try this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Islamic_and_Jewish_dietary_laws) comparing the two sets of laws.

I can only describe the Jewish perspective here, but apparently many Islamic scholars feel that a kosher chicken can also be a Halal chicken. The slaughter is done by a monotheist using the appropriate technique, and the name of God is pronounced before slaughter ("bless you God, Lord of the Universe, who commanded us regarding slaughter"). Whichever Islamic authority allowed the Halal designation presumably followed this point of view.